# Finding the unit vector indicating direction from A to B

Tags: vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

Given vector A and vector B, how can I find the unit vector indicating the direction from A to B?

For example (U is the found unit vector):

- A = 2,3
- B = 2,6
- U = 0,1

Assume 2D space and low mathematical skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(B-A)/ \parallel B-A \parallel$

where the numerator is a vector in the direction which is the difference between $B$ and $A$ (think of the arrow as starting at A and ending at B, except that being a vector, it is pointed at the origin).

The denominator is the norm of the above vector, ie, the normalization factor that yields a unit vector.

This works in all finite dimensional vector spaces not just $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Wouldn't you then have to normalize the final result to get the unit vector?

Comment: Dividing by $\parallel B-A \parallel$ yields the unit vector (except when $B-A$ of course in which case direction is not well defined). In your example, $B-A=(2,6)-(2,3)=(0,3)$ which is not a unit vector. Dividing by  $\parallel B-A \parallel = 3$ gives your $(0,1)$

Comment: So let me get this straight... The numerator is B - A. The denominator is B - A normalized. That's it? Because that's not working for me. The final result isn't a unit vector until it's normalized. For example, I use that algorithm with A=(496,112) and B=(464,112) and it gives me U=(32,0), which isn't a unit vector. And even if it was, it would be wrong as I'd expect (-1,0), not (1,0). I may be just doing something wrong (doing this via programming in C#).

Comment: The denominator is the *norm* of $B-A$. $\parallel (464,112) - (496,112) \parallel = (-32,0)$ and the norm of $(-32,0)$ is 32, so the unit vector is $(-1,0)$

Comment: And isn't ∥B−A∥ = (0,1), not 3? I'm confused. Shouldn't normalizing return a unit vector? Like I said, assume low mathematical skills.

Comment: No, the norm is a scalar quantity (its length) not a vector.

Comment: So I'm getting norm confused with normalize. Aiii. I'll try it again with this new info.

Comment: Thanks for putting up with the confusion, got it working. Had to deal with a NaN issue due to the possibility of dividing by zero but got everything working as expected.

Comment: No problem and like I mentioned above, if $B=A$, then there is no direction; the norm will be zero, so this exception must be handled.